# "faa-wings" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I just edited a [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14740/1289) about FAA regulations applying to aircraft wings incorrectly tagged "faa-wings"

I added a description (based on copying chunks from Wikipedia and an FAA document) to the tag to make clear that the presumed creator of that tag (who wrote the only two prior questions with that tag) mean it to apply to the FAA pilot-proficiency program, not to actual wings.

Is this little-used tag useful? Could it be renamed something that is less likely to be applied in error (or is a good tag description enough)

Comment: I've made the change suggested by Pondlife and renamed [tag:faa-wings] to [tag:faa-wings-program]. This should make it less confusing for people.

Answer (score 13):

It's hard to say if it's useful or not: it only has two questions today but that doesn't mean we won't get more in the future. I think we should leave it there, but rename it to [faa-wings-program](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa-wings-program).

And if someone has a question on FAA regulations applied to aircraft wings then IMO the most appropriate tagging is [faa-regulations](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa-regulations) plus [wing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wing).

Comment: I agree 100%...